# How to encrypt with Twofish using ECB cipher mode and PKCS7 block padding mode?

Tags: php, encryption, pkcs#7, ecb, twofish

I want to access an API with PHP. The specifications are:

- Twofish algorithm
- ECB cipher mode
- PKCS7 block padding mode

I have tried a lot of different PHP functions and libraries, but none seems to work.

Here is my code:

```
function encrypt($data, $key)
{
  // Pad for PKCS7
  $blockSize = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_TWOFISH, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
  $len = strlen($data);
  $pad = $blockSize - ($len % $blockSize);
  $data .= str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);

  $encryptedData = mcrypt_encrypt( MCRYPT_TWOFISH, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);

  return $encryptedData;
}
```

**Do you see a problem with this code?**

Comment: No. What is it doing that it shouldn't? What isn't it doing that it should? And now for the standard: 1. Mcrypt is deprecated and unmaintained, use OpenSSL. 2. ECB is the opposite of secure.

Comment: Sadly OpenSSL does not support the Twofish algorithm. Yeah I know that these encryption methods are not secure. However I don't care, because I can not change the API and the encrypted data is tunneled through SSL.

Answer (score 0):

`mcrypt_encrypt` does not support PKCS7 padding.  It has also been deprecated for a significant period of time.

If the API you want to talk to is using Twofish and ECB mode then you probably don't want to use that API at all - if they're happy to whack an incredibly insecure encryption scheme together for the front-facing API then the rest of their codebase is probably pretty shammy too.

Comment: Yeah I know that these encryption methods are not secure or at least not the yellow of the egg. However I don't care, because I can not change the API and the encrypted data is tunneled through SSL.

Comment: IIRC all you really need to do to shoehorn in PKCS7 is NULL-pad the input data to be a multiple of the block size, and make allowances for the padding after decryption.